# Exactly how many primitive data types are there in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that it might not be important to know but it's purely based on my curiosity. I've looked everywhere on the internet and every website had different numbers which was really frustrating. this website (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) shows 28 primitive data types for C++ while others show different numbers. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Those are data types that is combined with the type modifiers.

Comment: So the type such as 'short int' is not primitive type?

Comment: @talent_developer, Primitive types are built-in or predefined data types. `short int` is combined of primitive type `int` and data modifier `short`. So it could be said like `variants of primitive`.

Comment: @AndrewLi, [the standard calls out "short int" as an independent type](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2), and doesn't use the term "data modifier".

Comment: @zneak, short int and long int are different data type? I think that both is integer primitive type. And it only has different size in memory.

Comment: @AndrewLi, size is a pretty significant difference to me. Just like `int[2]` and `int[4]` are different types and can't be derived from one another, even though fundamentally they're "just arrays of integers". Regardless, I'm not making up the standard, and that's what it says.

Comment: @zneak, what is the concept of primitive data type in c++?

Comment: @AndrewLi, it is not a specified term, and so it has no standard meaning. I think that "fundamental type" (which *is* a specified term) is close enough, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177770/discussion-between-andrew-li-and-zneak).

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you count the data types. [This web site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm) lists these 7:

- `bool`
- `char`
- `int`
- `float`
- `double`
- `void`
- `wchar_t`

However, these types can be modified with `signed`, `unsigned`, `short`, `long`.  The site that you mentioned lists all of these, plus the new ones like `char16_t` and `char32_t`.  I think that the 28 listed is a very comprehensive list, and I can't think of any that have been omitted (they've even covered `unsigned long long int`).

So, 28 looks right to me.  The reason other sites my have different numbers is because they don't include the new ones, or they don't count all of the modifiers.  Other sites may consider `unsigned short int` different from `short unsigned int`, but the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> Primitive Data Types:  These data types are built-in or predefined
>   data types and can be used directly by the user to declare variables.
>   example: int, char , float, bool etc.

Primitive data types available in C++ are:

- Integer
- Character
- Boolean
- Floating Point
- Double Floating Point
- Valueless or Void
- Wide Character

You think that the `short int` and `long int` are primitive data types.
Those are combined with primitive data type `int` and data modifier `short` and `long`.

> Datatype Modifiers: As the name implies, datatype modifiers are used with the built-in data types to modify the length of data that a particular data type can hold.

Data type modifiers available in C++ are:

- Signed
- Unsigned
- Short
- Long

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-data-types/) gives you the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Primitive data type" is not a term that the standard specifies, so you might get a different answer depending on who you ask. Clang [defines](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/AST/BuiltinTypes.def) the following types as "built-in", meaning that they aren't derived from any other type:

- `void`
- `bool`
- `std::nullptr_t`
- `float`
- `double`
- `long double`
- `char16_t`
- `char32_t`
- `signed` and `unsigned` variants of:

  - `char`
  - `wchar_t`
  - `short`
  - `int`
  - `long`
  - `long long`

The list contains more, but I believe that those are the only ones that are specified in standard C++.

The standard has essentially the same thing in [[basic.fundamental]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) (calling these "fundamental types"), but the list isn't as convenient to navigate.

That would be a total of 20 primitive types (ignoring that `char` and `wchar_t` are treated separately from their explicitly `signed`/`unsigned` variants, because their default signedness is platform-dependent).

The standard also allows implementations to have "extended" signed and unsigned integer types. For instance, Clang supports a signed and unsigned `__int128_t`, which would fall in that category, but it isn't required by the standard.